# How can I cache an html document in a users browser?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, caching

I recently visited a website called neocities.org
I was surprised to see how extremely fast their pages loaded after a refresh because it's grabbing content from my browser cache..
exe. apple.neocities.com suyu.neocities.org
After some exploring I found that their site caches all content in the browser with a status 304. It also shows 'cache' on the html document line within the network tab on inspect element.
How can I accomplish this?
Do I need to have http/2 enabled to do this?

I have tried numerous things and nothing worked.
I did enable gzip though which was also enabled on these sites.
I put the code below in my .htaccess

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I would like to enable some sort of caching that caches every file on my website in a users browser with a status of 304 instead of grabbing the file from the server each time.

Comment: Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching

Comment: I have just tried to do it based off of that. No luck.

Comment: Which part doesn't work? If you examine the 'response headers' that your server is sending out, does the relevant cache directive get set? Or does the problem lie with the browser not honouring these 'hints'?

Comment: I think it just has to do with Apache. I switched over to nginx and now is caches it.